# Premiere Pro CS6 preview problem: other application shows through

Tags: premiere, encoding

Sorry if this is the wrong place to ask this question, but, I'm having a issue with Premiere Pro CS6 from Creative Cloud.  Whenever I put footage in the timeline this happens: [image: problem image].  The file's encoding is fine and it happens with every file.  I'm running it on a MacBook Pro Retina.  Does anyone have any ideas on how I could try and get Premiere working?

Comment: You might also get knowledgeable answers on superuser from people who know the Mac display libraries well if my suggestions don't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like a problem with the playback engine.  I would try updating your video card drivers and/or making sure the playback engine (in the project/ project settings/general menu) is set to Mercury Playback Engine Software Only.  If that doesn't work, I'd try uninstalling and re-installing Premiere.

I don't know what can cause it on Mac OS, but on Windows seeing something from another application through a portion of a window is generally a sign of a graphics driver being misconfigured or misused by the software in question.

Comment: That fixed it! Wow, thanks so much.  I would have never thought of that!

Comment: @SamBaumgarten out of curiosity, which one of the suggestions fixed it?

Comment: Changing the playback engine :)